# My sliding menu in React does not work?

Tags: reactjs, animation, slide

follow the [tutorial](https://www.kirupa.com/react/smooth_sliding_menu_react_motion.htm) but apparently does not work as it should, by pressing the button should appear the menu on the right side but it appears in this way, what is wrong?

the MenuContainer class change it to SideBar.js

all classes are inside **SideBar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class SideBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { visible: false };
        this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
        this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    }

    toggleMenu() {
      this.setState({
          visible: !this.state.visible
      });
    }

    handleMouseDown(e) {
        this.toggleMenu();

        console.log("clicked");
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
  render() {
    return (

    <div>

    <MenuButton handleMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}/>
    <Menu handleMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown} menuVisibility={this.state.visible}/>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Can you spot the item that doesn't belong?</p>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Ipsum</li>
            <li>Dolor</li>
            <li>Sit</li>
            <li>Bumblebees</li>
            <li>Aenean</li>
            <li>Consectetur</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div> 

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SideBar;

class MenuButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="roundButton"
              onMouseDown={this.props.handleMouseDown}></button>
    );
  }
}


class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var visibility = "hide";

    if (this.props.menuVisibility) {
      visibility = "show";
    }

    return (
      <div className="flyoutMenu"
           onMouseDown={this.props.handleMouseDown} 
           className={visibility}>
        <h2><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">About</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">Search</a></h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and my **styles.scss**

```
.roundButton {
  background-color: #96D9FF;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #0065A6;
  outline: none;
  transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0, 1.26, .8, 1.28);
}
.roundButton:hover {
  background-color: #96D9FF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #003557;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.roundButton:active {
  border-color: #003557;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.flyoutMenu {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FFE600;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform .3s
              cubic-bezier(0, .52, 0, 1);
  overflow: scroll;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.flyoutMenu.hide {
  transform: translate3d(-100vw, 0, 0);
}

.flyoutMenu.show {
  transform: translate3d(0vw, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is the image of how it is displayed when you click on it.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLMrx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mutate the state from SideBar component. Sidebar component passes down state to Menu as a prop. When you mutate this state, it should re-render the Menu component with the new value.

Your menu class would look something better like:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { menuVisibility } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="flyoutMenu"
           onMouseDown={this.props.handleMouseDown}
           className={menuVisibility ? 'show' : 'hide'}>
        <h2><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">About</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="#">Search</a></h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi Frank ! I have the same error, you could check my code in the following link https://jsfiddle.net/emeery/mqm6LeL1/ please help me !

Comment: Hola... he arreglado muchas cosas. Voy medio borracho asi que no me acuerdo de la mitad. Pero en JSFiddle no puedes usar ES6 Imports/Exports, primer error; segundo error, hay que incluir las librerias react y reactdom (en external resources), tercer error, faltavan varios componentes por definir: Container, Row, Col; que supongo que los usas de un framework de componentes?

Este link funciona (creo que es lo esperado):
https://jsfiddle.net/mqm6LeL1/4/

Comment: Parece que eres un poco principiante en react pero sabes mas o menos de que va el tema. Mola ehh??? Preguntame cualquier otra duda que tengas

Comment: Frankies yo nuevamente saber porque no funciona mi jsfiddle ? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emeery/mqm6LeL1/23/) lo realice de la misma forma que tu pero no queda como el tuyo.

Comment: quisiera que me ayudaras con una animacion en react parecida a este snippet